# Не работает CSS В HTML файле

Tags: html, css

Такая проблема, у меня не работает css файл на локальном сервере, в коде вроде ошибок нету, вчера все работало. PS Тут вставленный код отлично работает.

```css
#user_info {
 margin-left: 100px;
}

td {
 margin-left: 10px;
}

//Файл не работает
```

```html
<?php
require "config.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Phptask</title>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
 <div id="user_info">
  <div class="user_info">
   <h2>ID</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="user_info">
   <h2>NAME</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="user_info">
   <h2>AGE</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="user_info">
   <h2>SALARY</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
 <?php
 $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `input_info_db`");
 while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
  echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['age']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['salary']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='delete.php?delete=".$student['id']."'>Delete</a> </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<br/>";
 };
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если бы Вы вставили код в виде текста, это помогло бы быстрее найти ошибку тому, кто хочет Вам помочь.

Comment: В общем у вас думаю style.css находится не в той же директории, что и index.html

Answer (score 0):

Задай полное расположение файла. Например D:/test/test.css

Comment: Не помогло  :( может это быть из-за openserver'a?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#user_info {
 margin-left: 100px;/*работает*/
   border: 1px solid green
}

td {
 margin-left: 10px;/*не будет работать*/
  border: 1px solid red
}
table {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 30px;/*будет работать*/
border: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Phptask</title>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
 <div id="user_info">
  <div class="user_info">
   <h2>ID</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="user_info">
   <h2>NAME</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="user_info">
   <h2>AGE</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="user_info">
   <h2>SALARY</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
 
  <table>
<tr>
<td>id</td>
<td>name</td>
<td>age</td>
<td>salary</td>
<td>и т.д.</td>
</tr>  
  
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Запустите и откройте код - нажмите на ссылку файла css - откроется и вы посмотрите, там ли это нужное.

Если нет- смотрите пути, обычно лучше указывать корень сайта `"/style.css"` - а если перебрасывает вообще в корень локального общий, то нужно настроить `htaccess` и прочее.

2. Возможно, Вы что-то добавили, и оно перебивает иснтрукции - например, использовали стили прямо в коде элементов.
3. inline стилей нет, но что-то перебивает- попробуйте указать `!important` к нужному.

У вас, вероятнее всего, все сдвигается, просто это не видно - укажите к ним border и увидите смещение.

*Пo коду - вы tr и td выводите, а где тег table?